# Measuring the impact of empty spaces in a SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been taught to never ever store unneeded empty spaces in a database.

I thought it was because of all the wasted space.

So I found a table with 3 million plus rows. The columns were twice as long in some cases due to extra spaces. Wrote a script to trim off the leading and trailing spaces and convert empty strings to nulls.

I used `sp_spaceused` to measure how much impact this had on the amount of space the table was using and I'm seeing almost none.

The only size change is `index_size`... and that changed by 1mb, maybe not even.

The data column is literally unchanged.

Is it the fact most of the columns are `varchar` that I'm seeing no impact? Or am I not correctly interpreting what the `sp_spaceused` is measuring?

Comment: Did you rebuild/compress the tables afterwards?

Comment: Did you defragment all the indexes after?

Comment: If you didn't defrag your indexes you are going to have page splits all over the place. sp_spaceused counts the number of pages used to determine how much space is used by the data. Here is the exact line from the procedure if you want to see it.

select
  reserved = ltrim(str(@reservedpages * 8192 / 1024.,15,0) + ' KB'),
  data = ltrim(str(@pages * 8192 / 1024.,15,0) + ' KB'),
  index_size = ltrim(str((@usedpages - @pages) * 8192 / 1024.,15,0) + ' KB'),
  unused = ltrim(str((@reservedpages - @usedpages) * 8192 / 1024.,15,0) + ' KB')

Comment: I did none of these things. It's just a copy of production that will be overwritten automagically, but if this were a real table in an integral database, it seems I would need to do this to avoid fragmentation?

Comment: "I've been taught to never ever store empty spaces in a database." --- this is a **weird** advice. If they are part of the data - you **must** store it. And there is nothing magical in a space character to avoid it. It is no different from a `.` character.

Comment: I've made an edit to clarify. I didn't convey the advice very well. I was speaking of pre/post appended spaces or fields that are nothing but a string of blanks. Although, what periods are you storing in a database? I don't think it's a good idea to store punctuation that can be easily appended on output either. e.g. a period on the end of street abbreviation.

Comment: @discosammy: I store application data. That's what database is supposed to do. It's application's responsibility to put data in a desired state. So if there is a space in the end - database must store it. Because that's what application requested to do. "I don't think it's a good idea to store punctuation" --- lol what? Please see what is the last character in this comment. (a hint: it's a dot and stackoverflow doesn't trim it).

Comment: I didn't say never ever store periods ever ever. I gave a freaking example and guessing whether something is a complete sentence or not isn't easily inferred by the application. Okay, so if you tacked a bunch of spaces after that period, you're saying that those spaces should be stored in the database? Why? That is the wasted space I'm talking about. Maybe the general wisdom has changed with all the terabytes floating around these days, but it still seems wasteful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the data types of the fields in the table.  Fixed length data type, such as integer and char(), use the same amount of space regardless of what's in them (with a few exceptions such as sparse columns).  Variable length columns such as varchar() only use the space they need.  If you have fifty empty spaces being held in a varchar field and you replace that with a NULL, now you are saving space.

One other thing to consider (I'm sure there are more) is how many rows fit on a page.  If there are four rows on a page and they are taking up the entire page, reducing each row by 10% isn't going to open up enough free space for another row to fit on the page.  SQL Server does not split rows between pages (again with a few exceptions).

As was mentioned, try defragmenting all the indexes and see if that helps.